# Swift - Assign Function to ToolBar Button Item

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have used a tool bar on the storyboard and i have some custom buttons on it.
How can I assign these buttons to the functions created in the Viewcontroller?

[image]

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: the buttons are created through storyboard.
and I do not know how to assign those buttons to specific functions.

Comment: eg : func menuButtonPressed(){
        print("ABC")
    }

Comment: directly you can use drag and drop the functions

Comment: just make an IBAction of that button.

Comment: but i fail to find the function on the storyboard

Comment: check your you are assign the class name for the particualar Viewcontroller

Comment: yes the storyboard is assigned to the correct viewcontroller

Comment: @szeto1121 - sorry now only I seen , your problemis solved or nor

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I can now assign IBAction now , but the buttons are not clickable which is the problem now

Comment: @szeto1121 - ok wait I will fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create IBAction for the barbutton item in storyboard like this

[image: IBAction for UIBarButtonItem]

**OR**

Create a function like this and connect with bar button item

[image: IBAction for UIBarButtonItem]

Comment: i have no idea why the button in my original project is not clickable
but when i created a new project with the buttons, they are clickable

Comment: May be you were trying to create action in another view controller class.

Comment: While I am just assigning a function to that button like what you did, it is not clickable as well